# User [USER_01] has an unresolved reference to Login [USER_01]

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, database-project, sql-server-data-tools

I have created a SQL Server Database Project and Imported a database (right click on project -> Import -> Database).

However when I build the project I get the following:

> User [USER_01] has an unresolved reference to Login [USER_01]
>
> DOMAIN\A USER NAME is not a valid name because it contains characters that are not valid.

Having done much research on the subject, many indicating changing the options in the schema compare tool I have yet to find a solution.

Any ideas of where to look?

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I'd search all files of type *.sql in your project for that "a user name" portion first. Could be that it's not properly quoted or something similar. We use a "custom" solution for permissions because we have different users/logins in each environment.

Comment: Do you want the user to be in the project for deployments? Did you figure out a solution?